# How is `org-contacts` installed?

Tags: org-mode, org-contacts

I have been thinking about setting up a list of my relations. Something to keep track of when we last met, what their food preferences are along with contact information. A normal org file will probably do good as a start, but then I started exploring if others have thought about the same thing.

Around the net I can find references to `org-contact`. It seems like it used to be distributed separately from `org-mode`, but is now located in the source [tree of org-mode](https://github.com/tkf/org-mode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/org-contacts.el). But running

```lisp
(require 'org-contacts)
```

fails even though I have Org mode version 9.3 installed.

My question then is: How do I install `org-contacts`?

Answer (score 3):

With information from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8toivy/tip_how_to_manage_your_contacts_with_orgcontacts/), you need the `org-plus-contrib` package that is available through the `org-mode` elpa. So to install it by your favorite way you have to add it to package-archives via (if you don't already have it):

```lisp
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Then the `org-plus-contrib` package will be available and you can install (using `package-install`, `use-package` or whatever) and then use the package with:`(require 'org-contacts)`.

Comment: `org-plus-contrib` would no longer exist (see announcement - https://orgmode.org/list/87wnzfy60h.fsf@bzg.fr/t/). All contrib packages are here now - https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/org-contrib.html. So instead of `org-plus-contrib` just install `org-contrib` package from there and `(require 'org-contacts)`

Answer (score 1):

`org-contacts` has been moved out to [a new repository](https://repo.or.cz/org-contacts.git) as of [release 0.4](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib/refs/release_0.4) of `org-contrib`